# ASSERTION FAILURE in IBUIColor.m - Xamarin.iOS

Tags: xcode, xamarin, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-mac

All of a sudden my Xamarin iOS project is not building. My last commited version of the Storyboard is working, but any slight change in the file producing the following errors.

```
MainController.storyboard : error : 2019-11-19 19:53:33.159 ibtoold[9510:345883] [MT] DVTAssertions: ASSERTION FAILURE in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEInterfaceBuilder/IDEInterfaceBuilder-15505/InterfaceBuilderKit/ImageCatalog/Library/IBUIColor.m:105

MainController.storyboard : error : Details:  nsColor should be an instance inheriting from NSColor, but it is IBUIColor

MainController.storyboard : error : Object:   <IBUIColor: 0x7fd6420a5290>

MainController.storyboard : error : Method:   -initWithNSColor:
```

Here is the full log: https://del.dog/obapeletof

Here is full xcode crash log: https://del.dog/oyibarutoc

If I try to open the file in xcode, it's producing the same error & crashing xcode.
I'm really clueless now what causing the errors. I have tried searching the Storyboard in xml format for nscolor, there is none!

Comment: Hi Ayan! The information provided is not sufficient for us to diagnose the issue. Could you share the code behind the storyboard and screenshots? Are you using a variable nsColor? Is it of type UIColor?

Comment: No, I'm not using nsColor anywhere in the whole project. Even searched storyboard for nscolor, couldn't find any. As I said, if I only revert back to my last commited version, its building and deploying fine, if I make any change in the storyboard, it's producing these errors. Which screenshots or code behind you need?

Comment: Need screenshots of "storyboard" when opened in the xcode interface builder. And code behind when you open the storyboard file in a text editor like VS Code

Comment: @AyanDas Hi ,what content you changed the storyboard ,even add a label in storyboard ? I think you need to check why show a error with `nsColor` firstly.

Comment: I can not open the storyboard file in xcode. Its crashing upon opening and generating same errors I gave above. I didn't used `nsColor` anywhere in my project and slightest of changes in storyboard like moving a view controller and saving it producing those errors.

Comment: Okey , if Storyboard file is from Xarmin project , then it can not be opened by Xcode . Here is a [WorkAround](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/troubleshooting/questions/error-ibtool#workarounds-for-xcode-60) for Xcode 6.0 , but you also can have a try here .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xamarin iOS designer for some reason removing my below custom color asset from the StoryBoard resources

```
<namedColor name="lightdarkcolor">
        <color colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB" red="0" green="0" blue="0" alpha="1" />
</namedColor>
```

I had to manually add this to storyboard code behind.
And it seems xamarin ios designer is doing this with color assets for every project(Maybe after recent update).